# How to show original publish post date instead of last edited date in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, plugins, wordpress-theming, blogs

I have just updated the post on my blog changed its category and now its showing the current date instead of publishing date. How to display the publish date instead of the revision/update one. 
[ED website](http://executivesdiary.com)
 A password to access is letmein Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hard to say what's going on without more details. Please update your question and add all the relevant code (eg. `single.php`) so we can help out. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must keep in a database field the initial date, and then you must modify the template in order to display the initial date not the last. But if you go to the Gui that can edited the post and you know the date you can update manual the date for a specific post. In Wp you can put feature or older date to a post.